# Azure devops - how to set dev branch permissions?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have a repo with master and dev branch.
i want to set the permissions for somebody who can read the dev branch but cannot read the master branch.

how can i do it?

Comment: Please specify type of repo (classic TFVC or GIT). Are you project admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Git version control. You can not set `Read` permission for branches in a repo. You can only set the `Read` permission in the repo level:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-git-tfvc-repository-permissions?view=azure-devops#set-git-repository-permissions
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-permissions?view=azure-devops